# Old Refresh Tokens are kept in [PersistedGrants] table after refresh

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

We are using Identity Server 4 for identity management with ResourceOwnerPassword flow and issuing access and refresh tokens and faced with the following issue...

We have short lived access tokens (15 min) and long lived refresh tokens (15 days). After each refresh of the refresh token, we are issuing new access and refresh token. Recently we faced a problem (with increased growth) that all refresh tokens for the last 15 days (expiration time) has been stored in `[PersistedGrants]` table, even after refreshing this token and issuing a new one old ref tokens are still kept in this table.

I don't know if it's desired behavior or some bug in our implementation, but volume of the data in this table is started to increase rapidly and is causing us a huge performance problems.

Below you may find internal quires of IS4 that are querying this table:

```
SELECT TOP(@__p_0) 
    [x].[Key], [x].[ClientId], [x].[CreationTime], [x].[Data], 
    [x].[Expiration], [x].[SubjectId], [x].[Type]  
FROM 
    [PersistedGrants] AS [x]  
WHERE 
    [x].[Expiration] < GETUTCDATE()  ORDER BY [x].[Key]

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PersistedGrants

INSERT INTO [PersistedGrants] ([Key], [ClientId], [CreationTime], [Data], [Expiration], [SubjectId], [Type])  
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6)
```

Maybe someone faced the same issue or it's just standard behaviour of IS4?

And only available option for us will be increasing lifetime for the access token for an hour and increase a DB size? But then I don't understand why IS needs this old ref tokens if we already issued new one.

(currently some users have ~10k ref tokens in this table)

Thanks!

Comment: You should make sure that `EnableTokenCleanup = true` in your OperationalStoreOptions.

Answer (score 0):

That does sound odd since `DefaultRefreshTokenService` will call `RefreshTokenStore.RemoveRefreshTokenAsync()` in this scenario if you're using one-time refresh tokens.

Are you sure you're using `RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly`?

Comment: Hi mackie, thanks for your reply. Initially we don't specify `RefreshTokenUsage ` on creation of our Clients (maybe you know what is the default behavior for such case?). But when I try to set `RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse` it still issuing new ref token on refresh.

Comment: Default for the property on the Client model is OneTimeOnly and that should delete the current token when you use it.